# .htaccess file issue / can't edit .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use GoDaddy Hosting Provider and when I edit .htaccess in cpanel, it take effect but after couple of hours (sometimes couple days) .htaccess is back to default. All my changes are gone.

My EDITED .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
#Maintenance Mode
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.11
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/berightback\.html$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/berightback.html [R=307,L]


ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Couple weird thing happens also:
 1) in browser bar my website is always without `www`
 2) My website's IP do not redirect to my website.

But the main question here is why .htaccess become to the default settings after I have edited it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your wordpress install. Anything INSIDE the `#Begin wordress` and `#End Worpress` tags get overwritten by wordpress. You need to remove ALL non wordpress rules outside of those begin and end comments.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Maintenance Mode
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.11
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/berightback\.html$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://my-domain.com/berightback.html [R=307,L]"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress

</IfModule>

ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month
```

Specifically when you make changes to permalink. 
You can see others with same issues. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-file-being-overwritten

Comment: Thank you! great answer & useful information. How about that IP and www "issues". Is it something in my end or should I contact to my hosting provider?

Comment: You need to add `OR` after the first condition `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx [OR]` as you have it now, it is saying both conditions have to be true (implied AND) which is not possible.

Comment: Actually if I add `[OR]` after first condition website shows: `The www.my-domain.com page isn’t working` and below that: `www.my-domain.com redirected you too many times.`